# laravel 5.2 run composer update at hosting

Tags: laravel-5

I developed my website and publish it on my host.while editing it in host I add package in composer file to use it. 
My question
How to run composer update in host and how to get CMD screen ?

Or
How to add package in host?

please any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This highly depends on your host. The usual "cheap" hosters are shared hosters. Which might or might not give you access to the cmd. Most probably you do not have root access - that makes a lot of things really hard.

One thing you can always do is running the commands directly from your code. You could put this code behind a specific route for example and remove it after the update.

```
exec('composer install my-package');
// or
shell_exec('composer install my-package');
```

You should look for ssh / shell access in your hosters faq. However I highly recommend hosting laravel applications on your own server or at least virtual server so that you have full access to everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification